# What are some good ways to share a public database?

Tags: database, git, odata, github-api, nosql

I want to put a database of transactions online (no private data) and make it available for public read-only access. I also want it to be easy for people to replicate, for audit/validation/analysis purposes using its history. Something similar to [Bitcoin Blockchain](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain) but don't want it to be dependent on distributed nodes for it to function. The best candidate I've found so far is Git as you can use it as a NoSQL database (see references below). People can easily clone it locally and it can be hosted on a central server such as GitHub. But Git as database is very limited and you need to have direct access to file system to be able to do frequent read/write, which would require a dedicated host. I was wondering if there is anything better or if there are any services I can utilize for this.

Thanks.

**Update**

As for size of the data, assume that it's going to be a stream of transactions that will start from 1 record and adds approximately 1 per minute. An external auditor should be able to verify that once a transaction is recorded it is never tampered with in the history of the data. Let's say I want to allow everyone to see what income flow comes to my business.

**References:**

- [Git (and Github) for Data](http://blog.okfn.org/2013/07/02/git-and-github-for-data/)
- [Git: the NoSQL database](http://opensoul.org/2011/09/01/git-the-nosql-database/)

Comment: Note that git allows you to edit its history. So you auditor can NEVER be confident that you haven't lied to him. The only way for an auditor to know if history has been changed is if he has a copy of the repo. Pulling from a parent repo in that case will cause a conflict which should tell your auditor something has gone wrong. BUT - he can only detect fraud for changes that exist in his copy. He cannot ever be sure that new data pulled from your repo does not have history that's tampered with.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to do this. And selecting which depends on the size of your data (and to a lesser extent your users).

1. Provide an API and/or a website. Most modern web frameworks actually allow you to do both with the same code by only switching the template for the generated data. For example, you can return a page for normal URLs but return JSON or XML data for specially formatted URLs.

   The API need not be anything more complicated than telling your users the format of your query parameters (or the structure of your URL)
2. Upload a flat file. Preferably in comma separated values (CSV) format. This is the route taken by most academic and government institutions since it's arguably the one requiring the least investment. Obviously, this is only really practical for datasets of around 1GB or less. But you can distribute large datasets this way as well. USGS and NASA have been doing it for a long time now. You just need to split the data into easily downloadable chunks (for example by date).

   For efficient distribution you may want to consider offering a torrent download and have a couple of seed servers.

   An alternative to CSV files that's becoming more common these days is to upload an SQLite database. It's basically a file.

Comment: Thanks @slebetman for answering but none of these fulfills my requirements. I updated my question with some more info. Specifically, the public DB should include all transaction history to enable auditing.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought the data in the DB **was** the transaction history. Now you're saying the data in the DB is something and you want to publish the history of all changes to that data?

Comment: Yes, the data is going to be live, maybe with a short delay, and it's adding up new records with unmodified history. Sorry if that was not clear in my initial post.